# Adsense Unsure About Application Process

Tags: google-adsense

Im trying to apply for a new adsense account, I have a pretty decent blog, running a premium wordpress theme, with a fair amount of content and get around 3000 visitors per day.

Yesterday I submitted the first step in applying for an adsense account which involved signing in to the account my websites search console and analytics is linked to.

I then proceeded to submit my URL and was told to wait anywhere between a view hours and a few days while day (Google Adsense) review my application.

Today less than 24-hours later I received an email back from google saying

> Can Not Review Your Site

weird as I have a 100% up record, no login required

Should I first create an add block and copy and paste that advertising code to my website advertising blocks before submitting the application? (however there is no option for me to do this) or does that only come in Step 2?

It is all a little confusing and the only reason why I can think that Google mentioned there is a problem with my site and they can not review it is because there are no adblocks set up... Or am I missing the pot here?

> Thank you for your interest in Google AdSense, but we apologize. After we reviewed the Portsmouth your décor. We can not accept you into Google AdSense at this time.
>
> We can not approve a Thomas Cor your reasons below.
>
> Can not review your site : While reviewing http://www.example.com we found that your site does not work or is not available in your host application through partners such as YouTube, AdSense or. Blogger Sites hosted may not be ready or not ready to serve the (deleted) whereas a review.
>
> You can see more details and tips on how to apply the provisions of
>   this glistening help.
>
> To update and resubmit Thomas cor of you again. Visit google.com/adsense and sign in using the e- mail and password specified in the Portsmouth your décor. Our specialists will review your account to your account to comply Goa on our program policies, so please make sure that you have solved all the problems listed above before submitting another ex counteract this.
>
> To review the rules, you're out to visit the AdSense program policies. AdSense and Terms of Service AdSense.
>
> For more information Please visit our Help Center for consultations for the Forum, help these waves of North. AdSense is a
>   community of publishers, advertisers can share good practice on part
>   of the AdSense Google AdSense representatives will participate in the
>   discussions.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Google is not very helpful sometimes especially when it is in their best interest to help you help them make money.

Comment: Does the e-mail say anything else?? Are there any clues? Do you think it could help to post the e-mail (edited to keep anonymous if you want)?

Comment: Yeah I will post the email - here is the ridiculous thing though - I come from an English speaking country, my native language is English WHICH i clearly indicated , my website is English, however because I live in a non English speaking country they send my an email in some gibberish, in my country of residence language which I now need to use google translate for to make sense of

Comment: Anyway email posted in comment

Comment: Yeah. I get it. I laughed too! One day, Google decided that I spoke another language and their tools were in a language I did not understand. I could have used Chrome to translate, however, I just waited till another day.

Comment: What you think should I re-submit the application or just stop wasting my time?

Comment: I have no idea. It may help to post the domain name in a comment so that people can see what Google and you are seeing. That e-mail does give some clues, however, I have no idea what the clues mean. Google and Adsense has gotten a bit more critical/cryptic in the past years. I am sure there is something to fix, I am not sure what it could be.

Comment: www.thesportfreak.com

Comment: Your site looks good. I did try it a few times and it took anywhere from 12 seconds to 24 seconds to download fully. When I looked at your code, I can see you have a lot of stuff in your header. I did not go through and decypher what is slowing down your site. It would make me go cross-eyed. I used Chrome Developer Tools and you can too. It may be that your site is loading too slow for Google. I am not sure. It would be good to hear what others say. For what it is worth, it is a nice site! Well worth working on. Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks mate really appreciate it, I guess my wonderful hosting provider `godaddy` might be the culprit here, it gives me the following message in my cpanel (see update in question) Ive been reluctant to upgrade my resource plan since I thought it was BS and just their way of trying to get more money out of me but maybe it really is the reason for the slow load time

Comment: It may also be some simple things such as too many JavaScript calls and the size of the JS and image files. Focus on that. Let's also see if there is anything else people can find/recommend. GoDaddy is fairly good. Your site should have downloaded quickly enough for me from GoDaddy. I would not switch unless you have to. Cheers!!

Comment: Your awesome thanks my man, I'm busy removing many of the unnecessary javascript calls. Have a ding dong day

Comment: You too brother!! I do like your site. You did a good job!

Comment: Could you install the [W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) plugin if you haven't already, it will make your site a lot faster...

Comment: Sorry but the question is to specific and application rejections contain far to many variables as your aware. It is best to use our chat channel for such questions.